# Mercurial Bookmarks and 'Git like branching'

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, dvcs

I am not having any luck using Bookmarks in Mercurial for Git like branching.

From the article: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/BookmarksExtension, I've set "track.current" to true in my .hgrc file.

Excerpt below:

> By default, when several bookmarks
>   point to the same changeset, they will
>   all move forward together. It is
>   possible to obtain a more Git-like
>   experience by adding the following
>   configuration option to your .hgrc
>
> ```
> [bookmarks]
> track.current = True
> ```

However, as soon as I start trying to do parallel / independent development on more than one bookmark, then switch back and forth between the bookmarks, I run into the following:

```
abort: crosses branches (use 'hg merge' or 'hg update -C')
```

Example to reproduce:

```
# Make a new directory and Mercurial repository
$ mkdir bookmark
$ cd bookmark
$ hg init

# Create two bookmarks
$ hg bookmark bk1
$ hg bookmark bk2

# Checkout bk1
$ hg update bk1
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved

# Create and commit a file to bk1
$ touch bk1.txt
$ hg add
adding bk1.txt
$ hg commit -m "bk1 file"

# Checkout bk2
$ hg update bk2
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 1 files removed, 0 files unresolved

# Create and commit a file to bk2
$ touch bk2.txt
$ hg add
adding bk2.txt
$ hg commit -m "bk2 file"
created new head

# Checkout bk1
$ hg up bk1
abort: crosses branches (use 'hg merge' or 'hg update -C')
```

Is this normal behavior, for there to be "crosses branches" forcing a merge or file overwrite, when moving between bookmarks?

For a 'Git-like experience' I would expect to be able to flick back and forth between bk1 and bk2, committing and developing on either, merging if and when I needed to.

Comment: what is your hg version? recent versions might just switch branches.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please upgrade to Mercurial 1.4, which was released last week. Then you will be able to switch between heads on a branch without warning.

Comment: Updated to Mercurial 1.4 and can confirm that it gives bookmarks git like branching behavior without the abort / warnings. Thanks.

Comment: buymeasoda: thanks a lot for reporting back! PS: I like your username :-)

Comment: Furthermore, upgrade to version 1.6 (to be released in two weeks) to get bookmarks that you an push/pull between repositories.

Comment: Just to continue with the announcements: the bookmarks extension is planned to be included as core functionality from Mercurial 1.8, which you will see in March.

Answer (score 2):

Using a Mercurial version earlier than 1.4, you can just provide the -c flag, as long as your working tree is clean (no uncommitted changes).